# Can not debug using Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt. I have just installed Qt SDK version 1.2.

My platform is windows 7 64 bit
Visual Studio 2010 pro 32 bit installed ..
Now I have installed Qt SDK 1.2 (which has Qt creator)

I have created a test project and it runs fine but I can not debug it.
When I debug the program I get this error message

- The preferred debugger engine for debugging binaries of type 'x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit' is not available.
- The debugger engine 'Gdb engine' will be used as a fallback.
- Details: There is no CDB binary available for binaries in format 'x86-windows-msvc2010-pe-32bit'

It seeems to automatically have picked up my vs 2010 compiler as I can see in the project build settings but seems like it can not use the debugger for some reason..

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012346/qtcreator-no-debugger-set-up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-debugger-engines.html), you need to download and install the [Debugging tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).