# QtCreator no debugger set up (Windows)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am trying to use Qt creator on Windows, and when I try to *Start Debugging*, it says "No debbuger set up". How do I configure it?

Answer (score 10):

This is documented in the Qt Reference Documentation on [Setting up the Debugger](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html).

You'll need to install the **Debugging tools for Windows** (installing the Windows SDK provides this) which will give you the `cdb.exe` debugger. You may or may not encounter an issue when installing the Windows SDK and require this work around: [Error when installing windows SDK 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366006/error-when-installing-windows-sdk-7-1/23032807#23032807)

Now, start Qt Creator and go to *Tools -> Build & Run -> Debuggers*, verify that you now see *Auto-detected CDB*. Then go to the *Kits* tab select  *Manual -> Desktop* and change the *Debugger* value to the *Auto-detected CDB*.

Now start your project in Debug mode (*F5*).

Comment: Note that there does not seem to be an issue with using newer versions of the Windows SDK with older versions of Qt (e.g., 5.7.0), I was able to use the latest Windows 10 SDK with the QtCreator that comes with 5.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

When we are going to debug a program in Qt Creator by pressing F5, F10 or F11, we need to have cdb.exe installed on the system or it shows the following message:

> “Unable to create a debugging engine”

To install cdb.exe on Windows, we need to do the following steps:

• Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/
• Click get the Windows SDK here, download the installer and run it
• Uncheck all boxes but “Debugging Tools for Windows” and wait until it installs
• Go to Qt Creator setting and click Manage Kits
• Select auto detected kit and find the debugger at its property section
• Click on the manage and specify to the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe
• Everything works well now

Arman Arefi

Answer (score 1):

Go to Extras -> Properties -> Compile & Run Section. See on tab `Compiler` if there is a compiler selected. If not select an compiler and set the corresponding debugger. Else you eventually have to manually add a compiler and locate your path to your debugger (MSVC and CDB for example).

Comment: Note that the setting is under the  "Build & Run' category in Qt 5.7.0