# QtCreator debugger not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I am using Qt 5.1 with Visual Studio 2010. I can compile and run C++ projects with Qt, but when I try to place breakpoints and then debug, I am getting the following error:

> no debugger set up

How should I set up the debugger? I would like to make it clear that I have been using Visual Studio 2010 with Qt 5.1.

Comment: sorry for the delay!!!! I try to download CDB...but it crashes during the process.... No offline installer available ?

Comment: Is it still unresolved more than one year later??

Comment: possible duplicate of [QtCreator no debugger set up (Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012346/qtcreator-no-debugger-set-up-windows)

Answer (score 3):

From the official "Setting up Debugger" QtCreator documentation:

> when using the Microsoft tool chain the Microsoft Console Debugger
> CDB, is needed.

See this part of the documentation here inline as well:

> Debugging tools for Windows   To use this engine, you must install the Debugging tools for Windows. You can download them from Download and Install Debugging Tools for Windows. Note: Visual Studio does not include the Debugging tools needed, and therefore, you must install them separately.
>
> The pre-built Qt SDK for Windows makes use of the library if it is present on the system. When manually building Qt Creator using the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler, the build process checks for the required files in "%ProgramFiles%\Debugging Tools for Windows".
>
> It is highly recommended that you add the Symbol Server provided by Microsoft to the symbol search path of the debugger. The Symbol Server provides you with debugging informaton for the operating system libraries for debugging Windows applications. For more information, see Setting the Symbol Server in Windows.

The documentation basically refers to the following `MSDN` url for downloading the native `CDB` debugger:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009/

You can also set up the symbol server or Windows if you wish to go that far:

> To obtain debugging information for the operating system libraries for
> debugging Windows applications, add the Symbol Server provided by
> Microsoft to the symbol search path of the debugger: Select Tools >
> Options > Debugger > CDB. In the Symbol paths field, open the Insert
> menu and select Symbol Server. Select a directory where you want to
> store the cached information and click OK. Use a subfolder in a
> temporary directory, such as C:\temp\symbolcache. Note: Populating the
> cache might take a long time on a slow network connection. Note: The
> first time you start debugging by using the Debugging tools for
> Windows, Qt Creator prompts you to add the Symbol Server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Microsoft Console Debugger (cdb)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463009/) (that is part "Debugging Tools for Windows" in wdk/sdk, make sure you select it if you install the wdk/sdk or it can be found as a standalone install in the link above)

Comment: when I try to download it, it crashes in the middle of the process. No offline installer available ?